# Understanding Some Makefile Syntax

Tags: shell, makefile

I saw a Makefile that looks like:

```
TESTTMP = ./test-tmp

# VANILLA REDIS CONF
define VANILLA_CONF
daemonize yes
port 6379
dir .
pidfile redis_vanilla.pid
logfile redis_vanilla.log
save ""
appendonly no
endef

export VANILLA_CONF

.ONESHELL:   # what's it used for?
start: cleanup
    mkdir -p $(TESTTMP)
    cd $(TESTTMP)
    echo "$$VANILLA_CONF" | redis-server -  # what does this look like when expanded, equivalent to what command?

cleanup:
    rm -rf $(TESTTMP)

stop:
    kill `cat $(TESTTMP)/redis_vanilla.pid` || true  # what's "|| true"
    make cleanup
```

Basically I need to modify it for my own use, but there're some lines that I don't quite understand. I've made the comments in the code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [5.3.1 Using One Shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html) The rest is answered by @Norman Gray

Comment: @MikeKinghan Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see the output of `echo $$VANILLA_CONF`, then simply remove the `| redis-server -`, and the output will be displayed on your screen.

In this line, the `$` is doubled as a means of ‘escaping’ it in the Makefile: Make expands the `echo $$VANILLA_CONF` to `echo $VANILLA_CONF`, and passes that to the shell, which expands the *shell* variable `VANILLA_CONF` (a common error in this context is to forget to double the `$` sign: if the line were instead `echo $VANILLA_CONF`, then Make would attempt to expand the *makefile* variable `V`, which, being undefined, would expand to nothing, and the shell would receive the perplexing string `echo ANILLA_CONF`.

The `| redis-server -` is just standard shell syntax, indicating a [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)): the text echoed into the pipe by the `echo` command is read from its [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) by the program `redis-server` (whatever that is).

The `||` shell connector means ‘or’: if (and only if) the command before the `||` fails, then the command after it is executed.  In this case, the command after the `||` is `true`, which always succeeds.  That is, this line in the `stop` rule will succeed even if the `kill` fails (there are other ways to express this in Makefile syntax, but I think this is clearer).  This is also standard shell syntax.

This may seem slightly confusing, because you have to be able to identify what is *make* syntax and what is *shell* syntax.  The basic idea with ‘make’ is that it sends each of the ‘rule’ lines to a shell process, after expanding *make* variables with `$(varname)` (or `$x` for (rare) single-letter variable `x` and various escapes such as `$$` for `$`, as above).  You might want to review the documentation for ‘make’ (the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)) seems to have enough detail to cover what you need, but it links to the more extensive manual, if that's necessary).

Comment: I don't understand why there's the "$$"? And I wonder what does "| redis-server -" do? Is it applying a key-value pair thing like: redis-server -daemonize yes -port 6379 ...? I just don't know how to interpret the syntax.